# Difficulty in computing a determinant to prove concurrence (barycentric coordinates)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, determinant, triangles

Here's a problem that I recently encountered from a handout involving barycentric coordinates. It involves Conway's triangle notation as well.

[image]

In order to find the equation of $AA_2$ which is of the form $u_1x+v_1y+w_1z=0$,
I substituted $A=(1,0,0)$, which gives me $u_1=0$.
That means that the equation is in the form $y=k_1z$.
Substituting $A_2={\frac{1}{2S}}(-a^2,S_C+S,S_B+S)$ which is normalised, I then obtain the equation of $AA_2$ as $y={\frac{S_C+S}{S_B+S}}z$
Similarly, I obtained the equation of $BB_2$ and $CC_2$ as $x={\frac{-b^2}{S_C+S}}z={\frac{-(S_A+S_C)}{S_C+S}}z$ and $x={\frac{-c^2}{S_B+S}}y={\frac{-(S_A+S_B)}{S_B+S}}y$.

Then, using the following concurrence lemma, I attempted to show that the determinant is $0$.
[image]

\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 & {-\frac{S_C+S}{S_B+S}} \\ 1 & 0 & {\frac{S_A+S_C}{S_C+S}} \\ 1 & \frac{S_A+S_B}{S_B+S} & 0 \end{vmatrix}  $=-\frac{S_C+S}{S_B+S}\frac{S_A+S_B}{S_B+S}+{\frac{S_A+S_C}{S_C+S}}$

**How do I simplify the remaining expression to obtain $0$?**

Comment: Not sure that will solve your problem, but my first step would be avoiding the fractions. Make the line $(S_B+S)y=(S_C+S)z$ and likewise for the others. Then your determinant will be a polynomial which is easier to handle. The result should be the same as getting your rational functions onto a common denominator.

Comment: Edit: Found out that I plugged Conway's Formula wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I plugged Conway's Formula wrongly.